# Ошибка в коде RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, redbeanphp

```
$sql = R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE confirm = :confirm ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $startIndex, $countView', [':confirm' => 1] );
```

Есть ли в этом коде какая-либо ошибка? Есть таблица products и столбик confirm. При добавлении LIMIT не открывается страница. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать? Можно и вариант через обычный PHP без RBP.

Comment: Да, не ', а " для строки внутри getAll

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!